# How to use relative paths in css?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, url

On my wordpress site, I currently have the following url in the css:

The image is stored:

```
http://localhost/sigma/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png
```

My css file is in

```
wp-content/themes/sigma
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work, & I don't know why:

```
background-image: url('../../wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png') no-repeat;
```

Please can someone provide guidance?

Comment: Remove `/wp-content ` from the relative path.

Answer (score 1):

**Use from style.css**
( Using relative path )

```
background-image: url('../../uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png') no-repeat;
```

Or (Use absolute path)

```
background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png') no-repeat;
```

Or better if you can move your image into img folder of your theme and then use ( in style.css )

```
background-image: url('img/iconsigma.png') no-repeat;
```

If you want to call background image **from a php file**:

```
background-image: url('<?php echo trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>img/iconsigma.png') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your directory

```
wp-content > themes > sigma
```

- You are at `sigma`
- `../` => `/themes/`
- `../` => `/wp-content/`

So now we you are adding `/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png` to the path.

So you are searching for an image in `/wp-content/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png`

**Solution**

You have to change `../../wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png` to `../../uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png`

Answer (score 0):

The url shoould be like this

```
background-image: url('/sigma/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iconsigma.png') no-repeat;
```